# Provisioning profile expiring soon dialog won't dismiss

Tags: ios

I recently hit this weird bug in iOS 4.3.3 on iPad. When it was locked, the "Team Provisioning Profile is expiring in N days" popup popped up and I wasn't able to dismiss it by hitting the two buttons of the popup itself. The only way I could regain access to the device was to restore it. Now I upgraded to 4.3.4 and hopefully the bug should be gone, but I didn't find anything like that in the changelog of the upgrade.

The device's log didn't show anything unusual, and I couldn't even turn the iPad off and on again because said popup is modal and you need to slide to confirm poweroff.

Did anybody hit the same misbehaviour? I couldn't find anything relevant on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same thing - iPad2 running 4.3.3. It renders the iPad completely unusable.

I was able to make it go away by deleting the offending profile from the device using Organizer (part of Xcode on Mac), then doing a reset (holding down sleep/wake button and home button for 10 seconds).

The iPad rebooted and everything was fine, no restore required. If you're using Windows you might be able to delete the profile using Apple's iPhone Configuration Utility: [DL1466](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466)